# Getting back object Object from validation using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

In my jquery function I set up some validation so that if a user doesnt enter any data into these fields, it sends back a message saying "please enter + whatever field they missed". However when I test this in my application, the messages I get back say object Object instead of the text that I push into the empty errors array. Any advice on how to fix this is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
 $('#formData').on('click', 'button.addRow', function (e) {
        const cloneRow = $('#tableData tbody tr').first();
        e.preventDefault();
        let errors = [];
        let data = {
            project_id: $(".project_id").last().val(),
            imp_or_ann: $(".imp_or_ann").last().val(),
            category: $(".category").last().val(),
            cost: $(".cost").last().val(),
            hours: $(".hours").last().val()
        }
        if (!data.project_id) {
            errors.push({text: "please enter a project id"})
        } 
        if (!data.imp_or_ann) {
            errors.push({text: "please select an option"})
        }
        if (!data.category) {
            errors.push({text: "please select an option"})
        }
        if (!data.cost) {
            errors.push({text: "please enter a value for cost"})
        }
        if (!data.hours) {
            errors.push({text: "please enter a value for hours"})

        if (errors.length > 0){
            for (var item in errors) {
                $("#errors").append("<p style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" + errors[item] + '</p>')
            }
        }
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/costs_hours',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data
            }).then(
                cloneRow.clone().appendTo('#tableData tbody').find(".cost, .hours").val(''),
                $("#next").removeAttr('disabled'),
                $("#link").attr('href', '/fundings'),
                console.log(data)
            )
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#errors").append("<p style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" + errors[item] + '</p>')
```

You are concatenating object try this

```
errors[item].text
```